# Question about a theorem on primitive roots...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Theorem 8.4 from David M. Burton, Elementry Numbrer Theory.

Let $\gcd(a,n)=1$, and let $a_1,a_2,...,a_{\phi(n)}$ be the naturals numbers that less than $n$ and coprime to $n$. If $a$ is primitive root of $n$. then

$$a,a^2,...,a^{\phi(n)}$$

are congruent modulo $n$ to $a_1,a_2,...,a_{\phi(n)}$, in some order.

Proof:

From the fact that $\gcd(a,n)=1$ we deduce that $gcd(a^k,n)=1$. (The following statement I didn't understood) Therefore every $a^k$ is congruent modulo $n$ to $a_i$.

(The short proof continues)

Again:
 Why every $a^k$ is congruent modulo $n$ to $a_i$(from $a_1,a_2,...,a_{\phi(n)}$)?

Edit:

**Solution to my problem:**

"By the definition of reduced residue systems, it is sufficient to show that all these powers are coprime to $n$ and that no
two are congruent modulo $n$"

(Sad and Happy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part proves that $a, a^2, \ldots ,a^{\phi(n)}$ are indeed relatively prime to $n$. Since there are $\phi(n)$ of them, and since they are distinct (if not, then $a$ to some power less than $\phi(n)$ would be 1, contradicting primitivity), they must be the totatives, in some order.

Comment: But still, how from $\gcd(a^k,1)=1$ to $a^k=a_i(mod \ n)$?

Comment: It shows that the list of powers of $a$ is the same length as the list of totatives of $n$, that each power of $a$ is distinct, and that each power of $a$ is a totative, which means that the powers of $a$ form some permutation of the totatives of $n$.

Comment: I'm sorry Nishant, but I still don't get it. I'll return to it in some other time. Thank you.